# Can I pass an object into a function that takes its fields as parameters?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function that looks somewhat similar to the following:

```
foobar: function(arg1, arg2, arg3, ... argN) {
   // execute function
   // return result
}
```

In reality, this function takes a *lot* of arguments. I am not allowed to change the content of this function or the way it's built.

I also have an object:

```
inputObj: {
   arg1: val1,
   arg2: val2,
   // ...
   argN: valN
}
```

where the fields of this object match the parameters of the function foobar *exactly* -- in other words, the fields are spelt the same, they're added to the object in the same order, etc.

Does Javascript have an built-in function to either pass *inputObj* into the function *foobar*? Alternatively, does Javascript have an elegant way for me to split up the *inputObj* object into its contents such that the values are passed into the function according to their keys?

One possible solution, for example, could be:

```
const arg1 = inputObj['arg1'];
const arg2 = inputObj['arg2'];
// ...
const argN = inputObj['argN'];

foobar(arg1, arg2, ..., argN);
```

but I'm looking for a way to avoid writing out the whole code block as such to make it easier to read.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can use `foobar(...Object.values(inputObj))`. But this depends on the properties being in the same order as the function parameters, which is not easy to ensure. So I wouldn't depend on it.

Comment: But I don't think there's any other shortcut.

Comment: I'm getting the following two errors when I attempt it (I call the function on slightly different objects both times):TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator

Comment: About this: `they're added to the object in the same order` Objects in JS have unordered properties. They may appear in order of how they were added, or alphabetical, or any other order. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069705/1220550

Comment: @PeterB See the updates in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. I was calling it with the spread operator in the wrong spot. I'm getting it working in some spots!!! Thanks!

Comment: That said, there are some tests I'm running where I modify some fields which are not passing, I believe, because I'm modifying the order which Javascript iterates over the object

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring.

```
const {arg1, arg2, ..., argN} = inputObj;
foobar(arg1, arg2, ..., argN);
```

Comment: This is probably the direction I'm going to have to take.